# how to set Response.Cache in abstract class

Tags: c#

I have this abstract class

```
public abstract class TestControllerBase {

}
```

and a class

```
public class TestController : TestControllerBase {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));

    }
```

}

how can i set Response.Cache in the abstract class without excplicit calling something in this abstract class. I have like 200 inheritence on the abstract class. So i want to set the cache in one place not in every controller

Regards

Comment: Can you provide a complete sample where you call the Response.Cache methods ?

Comment: @RomEh now its updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public abstract class TestControllerBase
{

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));

    } 
}

public class TestController : TestControllerBase
{
}

public class TestController2 : TestControllerBase
{

    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Do my own stuff

        base.Index();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes but then i need to implement this in my 200 controllers right? Isnt there a way just to inherit this without calling base.Index()

Comment: No you don't, as shown in the TestController sample. The second sample just shows a way to add custom code.

Comment: Yes this Index() needs to return something then its a go =)

Comment: If the statements are specific to your controller, yes, you will have to override the Index metho and call the base method.